# "break-before: avoid-column" not working in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I am a hobby coder working on a personal website, learning as I go. As a sort of index page, I've created an alphabetized list split across multiple columns, with subsections for each letter. I wanted to avoid having these subsections split across columns; e.g., keeping the "B" subheader and all of the entries starting with "B" in the same column, either by pushing the column break forward or back.

It seemed like applying the CSS property `break-before: avoid-column;` to the `<li>` elements would do the trick, and in Edge and Chrome it's working the way I had hoped. However, I primarily use Firefox, where this seems to have no effect. My Firefox is up to date (v 121.0.1) and everything I can find online says this property should be supported in this version, so I'm kind of stumped. Any insight on what might be going on and how I could work around it?

**CSS**

```
.index-list {
  column-width: 150px;
}

.index-list li {
  break-before: avoid-column;
}
```

**HTML**

```
<ul class="index-list" ">
  <h2>A</h2>
  <li>Anteater</li>
  <li>Apple</li>
  <li>Asteroid</li>
  <h2>B</h2>
  <li>Bouncy Ball</li>
  <li>Bumblebee</li>
  <li>and so on...</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before, `avoid-column` is not supported in Firefox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-before#browser_compatibility) on MDN! and click the tab on the right named:

> browser_compatibility

It seems like Firefox supports the property `break-before`, but it doesnt support `avoid-column` so far(2024/1/15),  which marked by red "×".

Comment: try property break-inside

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't realized that a browser could support some values for a property and not others.